# How do I get the package of a local variable declaration in PMD and XPath?

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

### My problem

I want to create a custom ruleset for [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) that finds all declared variables that use a specific package. And it should be a **XPath** ruleset, because that is easier to maintain for me.

### What I have so far

I am able to find `import` statements and variables. I'm using this **XPath** to find the declarations:

```
//VariableDeclarator[../Type
                          /ReferenceType
                             /ClassOrInterfaceType
                                [@Image = 'ClassA']]
```

However, this is only matching the exact class, but I want to check if this class comes from package `my.package` and I don't know how to get that.

Any hints?

Comment: No XML document is provided! How do you think one could construct any XPath expression against a hypothethical document?

Comment: Well, because I assume that anyone with experience with PMD knows what is meant by `VariableDeclarator` and the other elements. No XML needed, because no XML used. I'll add the **java** tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I used PMD, and I'm going from memory here, but try preceding your XPath with:

`//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[preceding::PackageDeclaration/Name/@Image = 'my.package']//VariableDeclarator[etc..`

Basically, it looks for a related node in the XML that declares the appropriate package. Like I said, this is from rather old memory, but hopefully it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: `preceding` is a nice thing, but I think it's impossible to get the fully qualified class name from a `VariableDeclarator`, because PMD is analyzing the sources, not the bytecode.